# Upload Video File on Dropbox in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to upload video file from local directory to DropBox.I had create a instance.Also My video file is no more than 3 MB.

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) DBRestClient *restClient;
```

and this is my code (After converting to data I saving locally and uploading it.)  :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];  //this is my local video URL path
NSString *file = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload.mov"];
[data writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
[self.restClient uploadFile:@"upload.mov" toPath:@"Dropbox/Path" withParentRev:nil fromPath:file];
```

I am receiving this Warning  :

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files_put/sandboxDropbox/Path/upload.mov - (400) Expected 'root' to be 'dropbox', 'sandbox', or 'auto', got u'sandboxDropbox'
```

Comment: looks like you are sending the file with path appended to it. You should only send the file in the format /yourFile. Do not include path before your file name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer for my code...We do not require to save it in directory.we can use  the local video path directly.Here is updated code :

```
   [self.restClient uploadFile:@"upload.mov" toPath:@"/" withParentRev:nil fromPath:[self.videoURL path]];
```