# Dropbox API v2 for uploading media files in iOS

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am trying to transition from Dropbox API v1 to v2. My objective is to upload video files to Dropbox in the app folder that Dropbox creates for the apps that do not require access to root folder. I checked [this](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#upload-style-request) tutorial but have the following confusions:

```
NSData *fileData = [@"file data example" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];

// For overriding on upload
DBFILESWriteMode *mode = [[DBFILESWriteMode alloc] initWithOverwrite];

[[[client.filesRoutes uploadData:@"/test/path/in/Dropbox/account/my_output.txt"
                        mode:mode
                  autorename:@(YES)
              clientModified:nil
                        mute:@(NO)
                   inputData:fileData]
setResponseBlock:^(DBFILESFileMetadata *result, DBFILESUploadError *routeError, DBRequestError *networkError) {
  if (result) {
    NSLog(@"%@\n", result);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"%@\n%@\n", routeError, networkError);
  }
}] setProgressBlock:^(int64_t bytesUploaded, int64_t totalBytesUploaded, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToUploaded) {
  NSLog(@"\n%lld\n%lld\n%lld\n", bytesUploaded, totalBytesUploaded, totalBytesExpectedToUploaded);
}];
```

1. What should be "/test/path/in/Dropbox/account/my_output.txt" in my case, as I do not access the root folder?
2. Whether the same code is supposed to work for binary files such as mp4 files (it uses UTF8 encoding in the sample code when preparing NSData)?

Comment: May this help you https://www.appcoda.com/dropbox-api-tutorial/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167561/upload-video-file-on-dropbox-in-objective-c

Comment: Both the links are about api version 1, not api version 2.

Comment: What should be in fieData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The "/test/path/in/Dropbox/account/my_output.txt" in the sample is just an example. You should supply the path for the desired location of the uploaded file in the Dropbox account. If you're using an app folder app, the root you supply will automatically be translated into the app folder itself. For example, if you have an app folder at "/Apps/MyAppName", and you want to upload a file named "video.mp4" into a folder called "Videos" in your app folder, you should supply a path value of "/Videos/video.mp4". That will automatically become /Apps/MyAppName/Videos/video.mp4 in the account.
2. The sample makes an `NSData` by encoding a string, but you can use the same `uploadData` to upload a file from any `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this path is */test/path/in/Dropbox/account/my_output.txt*.

In dropbox account it will create folders like this test>path>in>Dropbox>account-- then your file will be in account folder. You can replace it with

***/yourFolderName/Yourfilename.extension***

Comment: Yes you just have to set change the extension for mp4 file.